# A simple StringCases problem

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

Given this text:

```
text1 = "  A  Vitamin D Deficiency (ICD-9-CM 268.9) (ICD-9-CM 268.9) 09/11/2015  01 ";
```

Yes, the ICD code values are duplicates- possibly but not certainly in all the records.

What string expression will match only the code values - twice if duplicated? I've tried:

```
StringCases[text1, "(ICD-9-CM " ~~ code__ ~~ ")" .. :> code, 
 Overlaps -> False]

(* {"268.9) (ICD-9-CM 268.9"} *)

StringCases[text1, "(ICD-9-CM " ~~ code__ ~~ ")" .. :> code,   Overlaps -> True]

(* {"268.9) (ICD-9-CM 268.9", "268.9"} *)

StringCases[text1, "(ICD-9-CM " ~~ code__ ~~ ")" .. :> code, 
 Overlaps -> All]

(* {"268.9) (ICD-9-CM 268.9", "268.9", "268.9"} *)
```

Removing the `..` repeat pattern doesn't alter the outputs. What's the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: probably .. is stronger precedence than ~~ so you're asking for repeated ")" (if you FullForm you can see this). also look into `Logest`/`Shortest`

Comment: In addition to the answers below `Union` or `DeleteDuplicates` could be useful to check for non-identical matches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply find the shortest match:

```
StringCases[text1, "(ICD-9-CM " ~~ Shortest[code__] ~~ ")" :> code]
```

> ```
> {"268.9", "268.9"}
> ```

If it is possible that there is additional space or other characters a combination may be more robust:

```
text2 = "  A  Vitamin D Deficiency (ICD-9-CM   268.9) (ICD-9-CM: 268.9) 09/11/2015  01 ";

StringCases[text2, Shortest["(ICD-9-CM" ~~ __ ~~ code : NumberString ~~ ")"] :> code]
```

> ```
> {"268.9", "268.9"}
> ```

---

[Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey) suggested a method scanning for `Except[")"]` to restrict the pattern to a single field.  I believe this is equivalent to my use of `Shortest`, but I was curious to find out how the two compared.  We can view the Regular Expression that *Mathematica* internally converts each `StringExpression` to with `` StringPattern`PatternConvert ``.  I will include two placements of `Shortest`.

```
StringPattern`PatternConvert /@ {
   "(ICD-9-CM " ~~ Shortest[code__] ~~ ")",
   Shortest["(ICD-9-CM " ~~ code__ ~~ ")"],
   "(ICD-9-CM " ~~ code : (Except[")"] ..) ~~ ")"
 } // Column
```

> ```
> {"(?ms)\\(ICD-9-CM (.+?)\\)", {{Hold[code], 1}}, {}, Hold[None]}
> {"(?ms)\\(ICD-9-CM (.+?)\\)", {{Hold[code], 1}}, {}, Hold[None]}
> {"(?ms)\\(ICD-9-CM ((?:[^)])+)\\)", {{Hold[code], 1}}, {}, Hold[None]}
> ```

We see that both `Shortest` placements produce the same RE.  We also see that the method using `Except` is more complex, and would appear to be performing additional testing that is ultimately unnecessary.  I would expect it to be slower, and it is, but only slightly:

```
textBig = StringJoin @ ConstantArray[text1, 1*^6];

StringCases[textBig, Shortest["(ICD-9-CM " ~~ code__ ~~ ")"] :> code] // Timing // First

StringCases[textBig, "(ICD-9-CM " ~~ code : (Except[")"] ..) ~~ ")" :> code] // 
  Timing // First
```

> 0.718
>
> 0.812

Interestingly the hand-written RE is quite a bit slower:

```
StringCases[textBig, RegularExpression["\\(ICD-9-CM\\s*([^\\)]*)\\s*\\)"] :> "$1"] // 
  Timing // First
```

> 1.872

I started a new question about this here: [Why is StringExpression faster than RegularExpression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25677/121)

Answer (score 10):

A couple of details:

- Restricting `code__` to `NumberString` will prevent it from being greedy (else it might stop only at the second `)`)
- You need to wrap the entire pattern (which is what we want to repeat) in parentheses to respect the precedence of the `..` operator.

---

The following pattern works:

```
StringCases[text1, ("ICD-9-CM " ~~ code : NumberString) .. :> code]
(* {"268.9", "268.9"} *)
```

Use `ToExpression@code` if you want them as numbers instead of a string.

Comment: Unfortunately ICD codes are not necessarily numbers, eg V58.11.

Comment: @alancalvitti Ok, but that should've been mentioned in the question. I don't know what "ICD codes" mean.

Answer (score 5):

With `RegularExpression` you could use:

```
text1 = "  A  Vitamin D Deficiency (ICD-9-CM 268.9) (ICD-9-CM 268.9) 09/11/2015  01 ";
StringCases[text1,RegularExpression@"\\(ICD-9-CM (\\d+(\\.)?(\\d+)?)\\)"-> "$1"]
```

Comment: Another way: `StringCases["  A  Vitamin D Deficiency (ICD-9-CM 268.9) (ICD-9-CM 268.9) 09/11/2015  01 ", RegularExpression["\\(ICD-9-CM ((\\d|\\.)+)\\)"] :> "$1"]`

Answer (score 2):

**Regular Expressions**

This is typically solved with pattern matching. You specify a pattern by creating a *regular expression* (or short *regex*) using [RegularExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RegularExpressions.html).

```
text1="  A  Vitamin D Deficiency (ICD-9-CM 268.9) (ICD-9-CM 268.9) 09/11/2015  01 ";

StringCases[text1,RegularExpression["\\(ICD-9-CM\\s*([0-9\\.]+)\\)"]:>"$1"]
```

yields: {268.9,268.9}

**Explanation:**

The regular expression language does have so called *metacharacters*:

```
\ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ? .
```

If you want to match these metacharacters you have to *escape* (prefix with \\) them:

```
(hello world)  <=> \\(hello world\\)
```

There are several character classes pre-defined in Mma's regex engine:

- \\d = digit 0-9
- \\w = word characters
- \\s = space, new-line, tab, or other whitespace character

(you can find more of them in the *Details* section in the Documentation of *RegularExpression*.

Imagine you'd like to recognize ICD-9 codes with a regular expression.

An ICD-9 code looks like this:

- two/three digit numeric code (may have leading zeroes to pad to three digits)
- an optional dot
- if that dot is present, there will be one or two following digits, depending on the preceding three digits. Which digits are allowed specifically is very variable.
- Some codes are prefixed by an E or V.

Your example does not include the E or V prefix, so you're lucky with the solutions proposed so far. The best solution, imho, is to specify a grammatic of ICD-9 code using a regex:

**Solution:**

```
StringCases[text1,
    RegularExpression["ICD-9-CM\\s([EV]?\\d{2,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?)"]:>"$1"]
```

This will match your ICD-9-CM codes and will verify on the fly if they are ill-formed (so to say, no match => someone produced a typo).

This regular expression is production safe and according the specification.
So you're safe :)

Comment: Interestingly the `RegularExpression` patterns are again twice as slow as `StringExpression` patterns, despite the fact that they, according to the documentation, are converted to regular expressions internally.  The problem is not poorly hand-written RE's because the generated RE's (see my post) used in `RegularExpression` are also slow.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard i just finished my post and then discovered yours. Yes, confusing isn't it? According to the documentation the patterns are compiled and cached. This seems not to be true if you explicitly define the regex on your own...

Comment: I would like to find a way to make the `RegularExpression` patterns as fast; it's troubling that they are not.  Unless you would like to do so yourself I am going to ask why SE's are faster than RE's and if there is a way to improve the RE performance.  Would you care to ask?

Comment: I'd like to let you take the lead, but please let me know or update your post, because this is really interesting in order to find out what's going on under the hood...

Comment: Posted: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25677/121

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the `code` you are searching for is a number, then I think the suggestions to use patterns which recognize such number strings are your best bet. For completeness I wanted to show another way which I think is a useful standard approach for such tasks and will work even when you can't make such a premise. The idea is to simply only let code match everything except the next closing parenthesis:

```
StringCases[text1,"(ICD-9-CM " ~~ code : (Except[")"] ..) ~~ ")" :> code]
```

or, if you prefer with regular expressions (somewhat complicated with all those backslashes needed as escape character):

```
StringCases[text1, RegularExpression["\\(ICD-9-CM\\s*([^\\)]*)\\s*\\)"] :> "$1"]
```

**EDIT:**
As Mr. Wizard has pointed out, this is somewhat slower and more complicated than the string expression shown above. That mainly is due to the additional complexity of allowing one or more whitespace characters (`\\s*`) before and after the matches. A slightly less complicated version of the regular expression which also is a more direct translation of the string expression is this:

```
StringCases[text1, RegularExpression["\\(ICD-9-CM ([^)]+)\\)"] :> "$1"]
```

which I would also expect to be slightly faster.

Comment: I don't think the `Repeated` (`..`) is necessary here.  Also, I think your first method is conceptually equivalent to my use of `Shortest` but I don't know which is better.  I need to explore this.

Comment: Your hand-written RE is not as fast as the one produced by *Mathematica* in my testing; do you understand why that is? (+1 btw)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: yes, I also think that it is conceptually the same as your `Shortest` approach, which I think is more elegant, but I also don't have a well justified opinion about what is "better". I have only seen your suggestion after I finished my answer, but didn't want to delete it...

Comment: Please don't delete!  This is an interesting comparison.  At a lower level (PCRE) your "Except `)`" is probably how these patterns are checked anyway.  I don't read RE comfortably so I'm not quite sure what you're doing in the hand-written RE, but I'd still like to know if you can figure out why it is slower than the rest.  What does `(?ms)` at the beginning of the generated RE's do, for example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: ... and no, I don't understand why the regexp is slower, I guess it might be due to the `\\s*` which might be expensive and are not part of the Mathematica string expressions. I can ususally achieve regexps to do what I want but am not good enough to optimize them, so I well could be outperformed by auto-generated code. Honestly, I was quite surprised (and proud) that I got that monster working at first try :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: just in case you haven't found it, I just happend to struggle over it: `(?ms)` switches on "multiline mode" (m) and "match all characters including newlines" (s). I found that here: [string patterns for perl users](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#759470019). The `?:` does, to my understanding, prevent the match to be assigned to a field like `$1`. I have no good reference for that at this time...

Comment: Thanks for looking that up.  Regarding performance, it's not your fault as the generated RE's used in `RegularExpression` are also slow; there is some "unfair" advantage for `StringExpression`.