# String pattern search and replacement -- it works, but produces error messages only the first time it is called

Tags: string-manipulation

I defined a function in *Mathematica* to process a pre-generated string. More specifically, I'd like to process some parts of C codes generated from MMA. Basically what my function does is to expand the `pow` function in C, so it involves finding a string pattern and replacing it. I know using MMA is not the best way to solve this problem, but unfortunately the language I'm most familiar with is MMA...Anyway, here's my function:

```
ExpandPowInCode[code_] := 
  StringReplace[code, Shortest["pow(" ~~ x__ ~~ "," ~~ y__ ~~ ")"] -> 
    If[StringMatchQ[x, ___ ~~ "+" ~~ __] || 
       StringMatchQ[x, ___ ~~ "-" ~~ __], 
      Nest[StringJoin["(" <> ToString[x] <> ")", "*" ~~ #] &, 
        "(" <> ToString[x] <> ")", ToExpression[y, InputForm] - 1], 
      Nest[StringJoin[x, "*" ~~ #] &, x, ToExpression[y, InputForm] - 1]]]
```

It works as I expected, namely expanding , for example, `"pow(x,2)"` into `"x*x"`. The `If` condition will help when dealing with plus/minus sign in the first argument of `pow`. For example,

```
ExpandPowInCode["pow(a x+b,3)"]
```

> `"(a x+b)*(a x+b)*(a x+b)"`

However, at the first time I executed `ExpandPowInCode`, I always got the following error messages:

> `StringMatchQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[x,___~~+~~__]. >>`
>
> `StringMatchQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[x,___~~-~~__]. >>`

Although `ExpandPowInCode` still gave me the correct result, the appearance of error messages was really annoying...Moreover, when I executed the function again later, the error messages no longer appeared as if everything were correct. Has anyone ever met this odd situation?

Comment: You might consider replacing `->` with `:>`...

Comment: @0x4A4D you always give me great suggestions! It works without error message now, but I still wonder why in my original definition with `->` the error messages only appeared once? Shouldn't they pop out every time I execute it?

Comment: Not sure why. Anyway, something for your consideration: `ExpandPowInCode[code_String] := StringReplace[code, RegularExpression["pow\\((.+?),(\\s*)(\\d+)\\)"] :> ToString[Row[ConstantArray["(" <> "$1" <> ")", ToExpression["$3"]], "*"]]]`

Comment: I can't understand quite what is happening, but by running `TraceScan[Print, ExpandPowInCode["pow(a x+b,3)"]]` twice, you can see at what point in the execution the difference is occuring. It is, not surprisingly, diverging some time before the error occurs, just after `Shortest[pow(~~x__~~,~~y__~~)]`.

Comment: I don't know there's "debugger" in MMA! Thanks @JonathanShock! Using `TraceScan` I found that @0x4A4D's `ExpandPowInCode` takes significantly less steps than mine, and it's also more readable. I really should start learning regular expressions asap...

Comment: btw, consider that it is still unknown why the error messages popped up only once, I hope this question could remain open so that I may learn the reason (or pitfall of manipulating strings) later from someone else's answer. Thanks.

Comment: @LeoFang regex is great, but you should keep cautious about the possible [efficiency trap](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25677/17).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is that the problem (and message) can be avoided by correctly using `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) rather than `Rule` (`->`) in your string replacement, preventing the evaluation of `StringMatchQ` before the string is substituted into it.

I believe the lack of a message on the second execution is explained by the caching or limiting of infinite evaluation that *Mathematica* uses.  This is a subject that I do not have a good understanding of therefore I cannot provide any true explanation, only observations; take any declarative statements as opinion only.

Consider the Trace output of this:

```
f = {head[3, "+"], Pi} &;

f[] // TracePrint
```

> f[]
>     f
>     {head[3,+],[Pi]}&
>    ({head[3,+],[Pi]}&)[]
>    {head[3,+],[Pi]}
>     List
>     head[3,+]
>      head
>      3
>      +
>     [Pi]

And a second evaluation:

> f[]
>     f
>     {head[3,+],[Pi]}&
>    ({head[3,+],[Pi]}&)[]
>    {head[3,+],[Pi]}

At least in some circumstances an expression that is comprised solely of sub-expressions that do not evaluate appears to be marked as not needing evaluation if it is seen again.

This behavior can be seen in a `Trace` of your question code, or in this condensed example:

```
x=.
g[s_String] := StringMatchQ[x, "+"]

g["string"];
g["string"] // TracePrint
```

> g[string]
>
> g
>
> string
>
> StringMatchQ[x,+]

Notice that the second time `g["string"]` is evaluated the expression `StringMatchQ[x,+]` is never actually evaluated; its components do not appear in the Trace.  Compare this behavior to the same code with a subexpression that will always evaluate:

```
h[s_String] := StringMatchQ[2 + 2, "+"]

h["string"];
h["string"] // TracePrint
```

> h[string]
>     h
>     string
>    StringMatchQ[2+2,+]
>     StringMatchQ
>     2+2
>      Plus
>      2
>      2
>     4
>     +
>    StringMatchQ[4,+]
>     Message[StringMatchQ::strse,1,StringMatchQ[4,+]]
>    (* remainder trimmed *)

The `h` function issues the message every time it is run because, due to the presence of `2 + 2`, it is never marked as not needing evaluation.

Comment: I too suspected caching and I like your reasoning, so it gets my vote. However, I don't quite agree with the fact that `StringMatchQ[x, ...]` is a pattern that doesn't need evaluation when `x` is a symbol (and not a local var). For instance, it needs to know if `x` has changed state, and indeed it does issue the warning again if you set `x = 1`. I don't know if there are other ways it is made aware of this fact — perhaps through the FE? If that's the case, then this decision might be made at parsing. However, I'm even more of a novice in this area than you are, so I could well be wrong.

Comment: @rm-rf I observed the same thing.  I don't mean to suggest that it never needs evaluation, but rather it is (apparently) marked as not presently needing further evaluation.  I suppose the symbols upon which the expression depends are also noted and if one of these changes it triggers reevaluation on next appearance.

Comment: I believe my hunch that it is done at the parsing stage is correct. Try this: `f[x_String] := (z = x /. y_String -> StringMatchQ[y, "+"]; z)
g[x_String] := (Clear@y; z = x /. y_String -> StringMatchQ[y, "+"]; 
  y = 1; z)` with `f["+"]` and `g["+"]` (twice)

Comment: Mr. Wizard's explanation is correct. StringMatchQ[x, ...] (when x is a symbol with no value) evaluates to itself, and doesn't trigger any side effects, so it is marked as not needing reevaluation. It is also marked as depending on x, so if you change the value of x, or do Update[x], then the expression will need reevaluation, and you will see the message again.

Comment: @ToddGayley Thank you for confirmation.  I must have read about this before but the memory fades.

Comment: Very nice answer @Mr.Wizard! I just have one more quick question. When I read @Todd's comment, I tested my code again with different input strings. What I expected was that for the first string I would see error message appear once, and when I changed it to another string, the error message would pop up again once, because the expression needed to be re-evaluated. However the error message didn't pop up in the second case as I expected; it appeared only once in the runtime. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @LeoFang Remember that the `StringMatchQ[x, ___ ~~ "+" ~~ __]` sub-expression doesn't depend on the input string until _after_ a string value is substituted for x. The warning message is issued before that point, when the expression is evaluated for symbolic x. Once that evaluation is done once, it never needs to be done again, no matter what argument you pass the function.

Comment: @ToddGayley, that's really nice (and subtle!). Thanks!