# StringCases functionality

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a list of strings in where each element of the list is in this form:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Aug 08 20:53:26 +0000 2013","id":365576505679568896,"id_str":"365576505679568896","text":"Who wears it better? #TBT http:\/\/t.co\/vAXNgiRmYo","source":"web"
```

I am trying to extract some specific parts of each element. I prepared this function:

```
extract[string_] := StringCases[string, {
    "\"created_at\":\"" ~~ Shortest@x__ ~~ "\",\"id\":" :> x,
    "\",\"id\":" ~~ Shortest@b__ ~~ ",\"id_str\":\"" :> b,
    ",\"id_str\":\"" ~~ Shortest@c__ ~~ "\",\"text\":\"" :> c,
    "\",\"text\":\"" ~~ Shortest@d__ ~~ "\",\"source\":\"" :> d,
    "\",\"source\":\"" ~~ Shortest@e__ ~~ "\",\"truncated\":" :> e
   }
]
```

And then

```
extract/@listOFelements
```

But as example for the element above I get this result:

```
{"Thu Aug 08 20:53:26 +0000 2013", "365576505679568896", "web"}
```

Some elements like the text flanked by `"\",\"text\":\""` and `"\",\"source\":\""` are not detected from the string. How should I make it possible to detect it?

Comment: Your first expression is not closed, it's missing the end part after web...

Comment: Even the first brace is a part of the string!! The string ends with no brace, as I have manipulated it before.

Comment: I can't copy the expression into MMA. It get's a error, where is the "\",\"truncated\":" part? Can you correct it

Comment: If the whole of your "list of strings" is one string, you don't have a list of strings.

Comment: I am just copying the text directly from MMA to web!
And I have a list of element which each element has the same structure as the sample above. But the information flanked by the parts in the formula are different!

Comment: If it's a big string, use \ before " as \"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you manipulated the string before and that's why it's missing a brace at the end. It looks like you may have deformed a JSON string, in which case you did yourself a big disservice as such lists can be imported by MMA.

Let's first repair your string:

```
str = "{\"created_at\":\"Thu Aug 08 20:53:26 +0000 \
2013\",\"id\":365576505679568896,\"id_str\":\"365576505679568896\",\"\
text\":\"Who wears it better? #TBT \
http:\\/\\/t.co\\/vAXNgiRmYo\",\"source\":\"web\"";
repaired = str <> "}"
```

Now, import the string:

```
rules = ImportString[repaired, "JSON"];
```

Extract the information you want:

```
{"created_at", "id", "source"} /. rules
```

> {"Thu Aug 08 20:53:26 +0000 2013", 365576505679568896, "web"}

JSON is a very popular data format, so you would do well to remember it and recognize it where it pops up.

I also note that you've asked eight questions so far and have accepted no answer for any of those questions.

Comment: The reason I did not accept the solutions is I realized non of them is a general solution but maybe a solution like the other answer to this post which is not a consistent one!!

Comment: And I have another element which is not importable by this function!!

Comment: @Morry Perhaps the problem is the way you're asking your questions, no offense. Provide a representative sample and I will be happy to try to find a general solution.

Comment: Please make a look to this case: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76785824/test.nb

Comment: Maybe you are right.... You were not offensive at all. :)

Comment: @Morry I recognize that, that's from the Twitter API? The Twitter API uses JSON. Now there seems to be missing a bracket or something that causes `ImportString` to throw an error. Did you do anything to this string?

Comment: If not, I would try to look at the JSON format and compare and see what differs.

Comment: There is a huge string which is imported by `xml = URLFetch[
  "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_\
name=BarackObama&count=50", "OAuthAuthentication" -> token]` and then is split by `StringCases[xml, "{\"created_at\"" ~~ Shortest@x__ ~~ "\"}"]` to make a list of Tweets. Then I face the problem in this post with the second tweet and some other!

Comment: It is the complete output https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76785824/test2.nb

Comment: Don't do any splitting, all you have to do is this: `ImportString[URLFetch[...],"JSON"]` and it should work. It should return a list of tweets.

Comment: @Morry I was able to verify with your second file that `ImportString[URLFetch[...],"JSON"]` works, or `ImportString[xml,"JSON"]`. The lesson here is; if they're nice enough to give you data in an importable format, don't ruin it.

Comment: Great! The nested `ImportString` works perfect! The very truth is I love People here as well Mathematica!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you first expression is text, I prefer the `RegularExpression` approach as follows:

```
str = "{\"created_at\":\"Thu Aug 08 20:53:26 +0000 \
2013\",\"id\":365576505679568896,\"id_str\":\"365576505679568896\",\"\
text\":\"Who wears it better? #TBT \
http:\/\/t.co\/vAXNgiRmYo\",\"source\":\"web"

re=RegularExpression;
StringCases[str,
    {re["\"created_at\":\"(.+?)\""]-> "$1"
    ,re["\"id\":(.+?),"]-> "$1"
    ,re["\"id_str\":\"(.+?)\""]-> "$1"
    ,re["\"text\":\"(.+?)\","]-> "$1"
}
]
```

you get:

```
{"Thu Aug 08 20:53:26 +0000 2013","365576505679568896","365576505679568896","Who wears it better? #TBT http:\/\/t.co\/vAXNgiRmYo"}
```

Comment: Something to consider: [(25677)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25677/121)

Comment: The fact is my text is longer and there would be some duplicates within this procedure. I would like to make a more specific patterns like this: `re["\"created_at\":\"(.+?)\",\"id\":"] -> "$1", 
re["\"id\":(.+?),\"id_str\":\""] -> "$1", 
re["\",\"text\":\"(.+?)\",\"source\":\""] -> "$1", 
re["\"id_str\":\"(.+?)\",\"text\":\""] -> "$1"`  where fails to make the proper result!

Comment: Can you give us a better example in your question?