# Please help translate regular expression to StringExpression

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I am familiar with regular expressions in other languages (e.g., Perl, Python, ViM), but the Mathematica `StringExpression` is baffling me.

I'd like to match strings that look like this:

```
1001.200nc
12345.220nc
987654.215nc
```

The regular expression I'd use in Python/Perl would look like this: `[0-9]+\.2[0-9]{2}nc`. What is the equivalent in Mathematica `StringExpression`?

Related: Can I use a `RegularExpression` wherever a `StringExpression` is expected?

Comment: `StringExpressions` are converted into `RegularExpressions`. I personaly prefer `RegularExpressions` form, it much more universal and easy to make your code readable by non Mathematica programmers.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25677

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me (that is very personal indeed), StringExpressions in Mathematica are much more transparant than regular expressions. Here are two StringExpressions for your strings:

```
p1 = NumberString ~~  ".2" ~~ DigitCharacter ~~ DigitCharacter ~~ "nc";
p2 = NumberString ~~"." ~~ (x : NumberString /; 200 <= ToExpression[x] < 300) ~~ "nc";

teststrings = {"1001.200nc", "12345.220nc", "987654.215nc"};
StringMatchQ[teststrings, p1]
StringMatchQ[teststrings, p2]

(* {True, True, True}
{True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: What confuses me about `StringExpression`s are the multitude of ~. Are they separators? Do they indicate a pattern? I'm not sure what they mean.

Comment: @Jeremy. The double ~~ is just an infix notation for StringExpression, so in between the ~~ we have the arguments of the function StringExpression. That is the technical explanation. More friendly is to read it as 'followed by'. So my first pattern consists of a pattern for a numberstring, followed by the string ".2", followed by a digit, followed by a digit, followed by the string "nc". In the second StringExpression, between the brackets you see a pattern for a numberstring that has to satisfy a condition, just as with normal pattern matching in Mathematica.

Comment: @Jeremy As Fred says, `a~~b~~c` is really `StringExpression[a, b, c]`.

Comment: slight variation: `p1 = NumberString ~~ ".2" ~~ Repeated[DigitCharacter, 2] ~~ "nc"`

Answer (score 3):

Replace `\.` with `\\.`, and wrap your regular expression with quotes `"..."` and `RegularExpression`:

```
regex = RegularExpression["[0-9]+\\.2[0-9]{2}nc"]

strings = {"1001.200nc", "12345.220nc", "987654.215nc", "nomatch"};

StringMatchQ[strings, regex]
(* {True, True, True, False} *)

StringCases[strings, regex]
(* {{"1001.200nc"}, {"12345.220nc"}, {"987654.215nc"}, {}} *)
```

Comment: So can I use `regex` inlace of a `StringExpression`?

Comment: @Jeremy, afaik yes (with minor modifications as in the example above).

Comment: Jeremy, in case you haven't, see also the tutorial :[Working with String Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html)

Comment: No I haven't seen that. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm reading it now.